# Large file size file not able to upload, return 500 internal error

Tags: php, file-upload, internal-server-error

I'm using Godaddy linux share hosting, and using the php.ini to configure the file upload max size

```
file_uploads = On
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

but this is not working, the max filesize that allow is 2mb, although i configure already, i have tried the "`php5.ini`", "`php56.ini`" and store it in "`/public_html/`" or "`root`" folder, it still not working, at first i suspect it is the problem of SSL, because i just install SSL 2 weeks ago, but i found that my another hosting account(no SSL installed) that i configured before and tested before and show it is working correctly also have same problem,

Can i know what problem? is it only me encounter the this problem? and how to fix it?

Comment: You found your solution. But someone who is using different hosting, they should restart PHP, after any changes to php.ini (just a note)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, we can straight away change the max upload size in system, follow this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YmS92xfmbFU